# Add Custom Fields in SOLR

Tags: solr

I am converting the `Lucene Search to SOLR` while migrating the project from `Sitecore version 8.2 to 10.2`.

In the current `Sitecore version 8.2 of the project Lucene is implemented`. I have updated the configuration and all most code-related changes. But in a few of the indexes, there are some custom fields added in Lucene in the schema on `SitecoreItemCrawler`.

```
<index id="project_career_master" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrSearchIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="core">$(id)</param>
    <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
    <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration" >
        <enableReadAccessIndexing>true</enableReadAccessIndexing>
    </configuration>
    <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
        <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
    </strategies>
    <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
        <crawler type="project.Website.Indexes.Career.CustomCareerSearchCrawler, project.Website">
            <Database>master</Database>
            <Root>/sitecore/content/project/Careers</Root>
            <Templates>{BB39C081-385F-1421-9T68-70C0RT12DA00}</Templates>
        </crawler>
    </locations>
</index>
```

Here in the above configuration, you can see there is a custom crawler written:

```
<crawler type="project.Website.Indexes.Career.CustomCareerSearchCrawler, project.Website">
```

**Backend Code:**

```
using Lucene.Net.Documents;

    public class CustomCareerSearchCrawler : SitecoreItemCrawler
    {
        public readonly List<ID> _templateIDs = new List<ID>();
        public string Templates { get; set; }
        public string LanguageName { get; set; }

        public override void Initialize(ISearchIndex searchIndex)
        {
            Assert.IsNotNullOrEmpty(Templates, "TemplateIDs");
            var ids = Templates.Split('|');
            _templateIDs.Clear();
            foreach (var id in ids)
            {
                _templateIDs.Add(new ID(id));
            }

            base.Operations = new CustomIndexOperations()
            {
                TemplateIDs = this._templateIDs,
                SearchIndex = searchIndex
            };
            base.Initialize(searchIndex);
        }
    }

    public class CustomIndexOperations : IIndexOperations
    {
        public void Add(IIndexable indexable, IProviderUpdateContext context, ProviderIndexConfiguration indexConfiguration)
        {
            var item = (Item)(indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem);
            if (!TemplateIDs.Contains(item.TemplateID))
            {
                return;
            }          

            var document = new Document();
            document.Add(new Field("_uniqueid", indexable.UniqueId.Value.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            document.Add(new Field("_datasource", indexable.DataSource.ToLowerInvariant(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            document.Add(new Field("_indexname", SearchIndex.Name.ToLowerInvariant(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            document.Add(new Field("_content", string.Format("{0}|{1}", item.Name, item.ID.ToString()), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            document.Add(new Field("_langauge", item.Language.Name, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            document.Add(new Field("_id", item.ID.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            document.Add(new Field("_name", item.Name, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            document.Add(new Field("_title", item["Job Position"], Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));

            context.AddDocument(document, indexable.Culture != null ? new CultureExecutionContext(indexable.Culture) : null);
        }
    }
```

with the same, update and delete method also implemented on Crawler:

```
public void Update(IIndexable indexable, IProviderUpdateContext context, ProviderIndexConfiguration indexConfiguration)

public void Delete(IIndexableUniqueId indexableUniqueId, IProviderUpdateContext context)
```

The above backend code is using the Lucene DLL.

I want to implement the same in SOLR, does anyone has inputs for the same, how to rewrite the above backend code in SOLR, please?

Comment: Does it need to be a similar approach with custom add/edit/delete? I think you could achieve the same result (i.e. custom index only containing specific templates + remove those with date passed). by using a combination of  < include hint="list:AddIncludedTemplate" > to select templates and < fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField" >  to set master item as unpublishable.

Comment: Thanks, Dean Obrien. I was also thinking of the same but it's a 6-year-old project and I do not know what is the exact purpose of this code. It's a multilingual website. In other indexes, the code is written the same as you described. In Sitecore SOLR the way to add a custom field is described here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/platform-administration-and-architecture/add-custom-fields-to-a-solr-schema.html   I am not able yet to decide which approach should I follow.

Comment: I think your best approach would be to figure out what the exact needs are as I'm quite sure you will be able to achieve them without a custom crawler. Upgrading projects and code without knowing what they are actually doing is a recipe for disaster and will always lead to unmanageable legacy code bases. Nobody wants that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the above issue and find the solution, I have explored `Sitecore.ContentSearch` DLL and found out it provides the below method in the `IProviderUpdateContext` interface.

```
void AddDocument(object itemToAdd, IExecutionContext executionContext);
void AddDocument(object itemToAdd, params IExecutionContext[] executionContexts);
void Delete(IIndexableUniqueId id, params IExecutionContext[] executionContexts);
void Delete(IIndexableId id, params IExecutionContext[] executionContexts);
void UpdateDocument(object itemToUpdate, object criteriaForUpdate, IExecutionContext executionContext);
```

In Sitecore 10.2 it takes a parameter object as a type of `Dictionary`. Hence I updated the code as mentioned  below:

```
var document = new Dictionary<string, object>();
document.Add("_uniqueid", indexable.UniqueId.Value.ToString());
document.Add("_datasource", indexable.DataSource.ToLowerInvariant());
document.Add("_indexname", SearchIndex.Name.ToLowerInvariant());
document.Add("_content", string.Format("{0}|{1}", item.Name, item.ID.ToString()));
//other fields
context.AddDocument(document, indexable.Culture != null ? new CultureExecutionContext(indexable.Culture) : null);
```

After building and publishing the code it's working perfectly fine and I get the result into the SOLR query.